# Hook up an automatic transfer switch with two phases only

Tags: power, switches, ground, generator, phase

We have a house in Haiti connected to the shore line. The shore line isn't always working so we bought a generator. I wanted to ground one of the two phases to create one neutral, one phase and a ground but people there said they don't do that. We had a lot of problems in the past we people getting shocked when they touch a freezer or a toaster. I keep saying that one of the two phases should be grounded but they won't listen, am I right to assume that?

Second question, I bought a Southwire Automatic Transfer Switch 50A Hardwire
Model 40100 to transfer a shore power to a generator when the shore power is down.

The switch box has three input on each contactor, L1 (phase 1), L2 (neutral) and L3 (phase 2). If I plug only L1 and L3 using the two phase it doesn't work. That's because the board uses L1 and L2 to detect electricity. Can I simply plug the ground to L2 and leave the two phases on L1 and L3, should I plug the L3 phase on L2 instead or should I consider them wrong and ground one of the two phases to get a neutral before the switch box?

It's worth saying that my shore line is a 220v line.

Comment: It's pretty hard to tell from reading this how to help.  Adding a wiring diagram and links to the product data would help you get better answers.  My recommendation would be to hire an experienced, competent electrician to install this for you, and put GFI breakers or outlets on everything that you are concerned about being a shock hazard.

Comment: I contacted a professional. From what he told me you cannot ground one phase because the voltage is not cut in half. They both give 220v. He told me to use the ground for the neutral wire.